# Повтор записей в DGV (чтение .txt)

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

такая проблема: У меня имеется есть файл с записями вида 1#Шмаков Е. А. Иногда это ФИО повторяется. Как сделать так, чтобы DGV заполнялось без повторов, те чтобы одно ФИО было упомянуто один раз?
Мой код заполнения DGV

```
StreamReader stud = new StreamReader("Students.txt");
        int k = 0;
        while (!stud.EndOfStream)
        {
            stud.ReadLine();
            k++;
        }
        stud.Close();
        kod = new string[k];
        name = new string[k];
        StreamReader studd = new StreamReader("Students.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            string[] sx = studd.ReadLine().Split('#');
            kod[i] = sx[0];
            name[i] = sx[1];
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sx[0], sx[1]);
        }
        studd.Close();
```

Comment: `var result = File.ReadAllLines("Students.txt").Select(x => x.Split('#')).GroupBy(x => x[1]).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault())`. То есть читаем файл построчно, далее каждую строку разбиваем по `#`, далее группируем все по тому, что идет после `#`, ну и забираем все первые значения, формируя результат. На выходе будет коллекция объектов, без повторов, разбирая по `#`, остается вывести куда либо, либо обратно сохранить в файл (вернуть `#` не забудьте).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое за ответ!